# Unexpected Token, expected }

Tags: react-native

I get "Unexpected Token, expected }" error while running my application.
I tried searching for this problem but couldn't find a solution.
Seems like everything is ok in here:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const myNavScreen = ({navigation})=>(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Button onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Home")}
            title="Go to Home"/>
    <Button onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Friends")}
            title="Go to Friends"/>
    <Button onPress={()=>navigation.goBack(null)}
            title="Go Back"/>
  <View/>
);

const MyHomeScreen = ({navigation})=>(
  <myNavScreen navigation={navigation}/>
);

MyHomeScreen.navigationOptions={
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, focused}) =>(
    <Ionicons
      name={focused? 'ios-home' : 'ios-home-outline'}
      size={26}
      style={{color: tintColor}}
    />
  ),
};

const MyFriendsScreen = ({navigation})=>(
  <myNavScreen navigation={navigation}/>
);

MyFriendsScreen.navigationOptions={
  tabBarLabel: 'My Friends',
  tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, focused})=>(
    <Ionicons
      name={focused? 'ios-people' : 'ios-people-outline'}
      size={26}
      style={{color: tintColor}}
    />
  ),
};

const SimpleTabs = TabNavigator({
    Home:{
      screen: MyHomeScreen,
      path:'',
    },
    Friends:{
      screen: MyFriendsScreen,
      path: 'cart',
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions:{
      activeTintColor: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '#e91e63' : '#fff',
    },
  }
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20  : 0,
  },
});

export default SimpleTabs;
```

It's says that the problem is in `MyHomeScreen.navigationOptions` block, but trying to delete it just causing the same problem in another block of code.
I looked for missing } or anything else wrong in the syntax but couldn't find anything.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The trailing comma...

Comment: @JeffMercado thanks, but it's not working.

Comment: Oh my mistake, but the problem seems to be in the `myNavScreen` function. The markup is invalid, the close tag for `View` is not a close tag.

Comment: @JeffMercado Thanks, I got another problem now but I think it actually worked... So stupid I couldn't see it :\ ..

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to delete an comma

```
MyFriendsScreen.navigationOptions={
tabBarLabel: 'My Friends',
tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, focused})=>(
   <Ionicons
      name={focused? 'ios-people' : 'ios-people-outline'}
      size={26}
      style={{color: tintColor}}
    />
  ), // Delete this comma 
};
```

And everything gonna be alright :)

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error, plus, can you please tell me when/why this comma should be a problem? never heard of it before and really curious.

Comment: @JohnDoah you are violating "arrow function" syntax, you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @Cherniv Thanks.